# Regular expression for thousand separator without decimal point

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have regular expression which is working fine for decimal .
In below expression I want to remove decimal match to validate Integer

```
^-?(\d*)(,\d{1,3})*(?:[,]|([.]\d{0,2}))?$
```

Valid Match : 1,000 & 111,  & -1000,00

Invalid Match :  -,1  & 1,,,,

Comment: What is your problem? Your regex isn't working as intended?

Comment: In given expression I want to remove decimal match ,rest need to keep same

Comment: What is `DECIMAL_POINTS` in your regex?

Comment: Maybe [`^-?(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:,0+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/cL6pU0/3)? Or can there be just 2 zeros in the optional decimal part?

Comment: No Need decimal part so Want to update given expression

Comment: Then just [`^-?(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/cL6pU0/4), right?

Comment: just take substring from the starting to index of `.` and validate it

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew   It should match 100,

Comment: Or [`^-?(\d+)(,\d{1,3})*,?$`](https://regex101.com/r/bG8bE3/1) if we just remove all the decimal related stuff. **Without comprehensive test cases, it is impossible to answer the question.**

Comment: The question is unclear and messy..

Comment: @VivekPanday: Does the last regex work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^-?(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)?,?$
    |---1---|
             |---2-----|
                        |-3-|
```

The `^` asserts the position at the start of the string and `$` asserts the position at the string end. `-?` matches an optional `-`. Part 1 matches 1 to 3 digits, Part 2 matches 0+ sequences of `,` followed with 3 digits, part 3 is an alternative to Part 1 & 2 combined and matches just 1+ digits. The whole number pattern is optional since the `(?:...|...)` is quantified with `?` - *one or zero occurrences*.

The `,?` before `$` allows an optional comma at the end, delete if not required (you mentioned you need to allow `100,` in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912876/regular-expression-for-thousand-separator-without-decimal-point/36914664?noredirect=1#comment61388409_36912876)).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP5tY1/1)

Comment: I answered as far as I could guess. Please add more test cases if you need a more precise expression.

Comment: given expression if working fine as required . Only my need is here to allow match - 
I am validation user input on key press so in my case user can start typing with -  (minus) which is valid input .

Comment: Ok, you need to allow empty string. Use `^-?(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)?,?$`. See the updated answer.

Comment: But this is a number with a decimal part. Read your title: *without decimal point*.

Comment: here , comma is used for thousand separator

Comment: Yeah, but a digit grouping symbol should appear after each 3 digit chunk. It cannot be placed anywhere just for fun in a number. What is the culture? I'd like to check. And try [`^-?(?:\d*(?:,\d{3})*|\d*),?$`](https://regex101.com/r/rP5tY1/2)